# node.js not stopping/quitting via MacOSX terminal

Tags: macos, node.js, terminal

After installing node.js and running it on a folder on my desktop, I'm trying to get out of the server mode which now my prompt says `android-eb1fe20915a73e2b:server usernamehere$`

I tried ctrl+c, running `.exit` also tried `sudo killall node` which returns that there are no processes running by that name. If I use the `ls` command I find that the user directory is still the same folder on my desktop.

Any idea what I did wrong/how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because that is the folder you are currently in *or* a server hostname resolved from dns. It's a normal occurance on OS X; [This answer from a similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/10139) might better explain how and why this happens.

In OS X your prompt is setup like this:

```
android-eb1fe20915a73e2b:server usernamehere$
           |               |          |
           |               |          |__ User
           |               |
           |               |__ Directory
           |
           |__ Current Volume/Server
```

Comment: Somehow it magically changed back to my Mac's volume... any idea why it changed to Android?

Comment: Check [this relevant link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23355163#23355163): this is related to the reverse DNS lookup of your Mac, which sometimes messes up in some network configurations.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMougel! This is likely the answer as I was at a coffee shop and moved to a library in between. Fascinating.